# sympy - Composition of functions and operators

Tags: python, math, sympy

Let's assume that we have a function f and an operator L. In this case, it can be something simple, like,

```
L[f](x)=\sum_{k=1}^{4}f(x+k)
```

My main objective is to compute compositions of operators, like L above, using sympy. Sympy has no problem handling compositions of functions but we can quickly see that there is gonna be a problem with the operator above.

For example, I can define it as,

```
class L(Function):

 @classmethod
 def eval(cls, f,x):
     k = Symbol('k')
     return summation(f(k+x),(k,1,4))
```

And this indeed computes L[f] but returns an evaluated object that is no longer a function of x, so computing L[L[f]] no longer makes sense.

Is there a way in sympy to convert what L returns to be a function of x? I think that would solve the problem, since then I would be able to re-apply L on the new object.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question had a simple answer after all.  Sympy's Lambda does the trick in this case and then I can re-apply L after evaluation is done.